# Cannot run local Bash script on remote system with ssh -tt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, redhat

Having trouble with bash. Essentially there are two Redhat nodes, WS01 and DEV01. The script on WS01 that I want to run on DEV01 asks for certain info prompts through a `read -p`. Expect is not installed and cannot be (unfortunately).

When I enter...

```
ssh root@DEV01 /path/to/script.sh
```

it returns (BoKS message)

```
no terminal authorization granted
```

If I do...

```
ssh -tt root@DEV01 /patch/to/script.sh
```

it returns

```
TERM: not defined
Illegal variable name
```

Script runs fine when run through a regular ssh session though. Checked term with `echo $TERM` and it was set to `vt100` on both systems. Default shell is `csh` on both systems so I thought it was defaulting to that. tried to put variations of calling bash in the ssh command but everything showed the same results.

Other variations of that ssh command (Feels like I've tried most of them) have unfortunately also given the same results.

Also tried

```
ssh -tt root@DEV01 "$(< script.sh)"
```

and basically anything else I could find on the internet and still nothing. Beating my head against the wall at this point.

Ultimately I just need a way to run a bash script that is local on the machine, onto a remote host, and that allows an interactive shell that will let the user input data when it prompts for it. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: how about a wrapper script that gets the local inputs, then calls the script but passes in the user's data? (hope that makes sense). I'm almost sure I have done things like in the past. Good luck.

Comment: sounds like your `script.sh` is doing some weird things. could you paste the script?

Answer (score 1):

The script is MOST LIKELY trying to manipulate the terminal in which the script output is being displayed. In your case, your terminal from which you are ssh(ing) into your script. For example, rewrite previously written output on the terminal. Linux packages such as `ncurses` comes with functions such as `tput` that allows you to rewrite terminal output.

This would be useful when say, a processing action wants to display progress and replace that line after processing is completed to display that the action was successful.

Example: let's say a file copy is in progress. And your terminal might display

`file copy in progress ...`

and this line would be replaced or appended to at the end of the operation to read

`file copy completed!`

You would need to remove the terminal manipulation lines from the ssh script file OR provide the necessary permissions (which is impossible in many cases).